# Going from a cube to a pyramid in visual studio using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

Hey everyone im trying to figure out how to make a 3D pyramid out of existing code that is already a 3D cube in visual studio by changing some of the code. I've been messing around with the verts as my friend suggested but I am still unsuccessful. Here is the code..

```
// ================================================
// | Downloaded From                              |
// | Visual C# Kicks - http://www.vcskicks.com/   |
// ================================================
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace EulerRotation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Cube cube;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tX.Value = 0;
        tY.Value = 0;
        tZ.Value = 0;
        render();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cube = new Cube(100);
        render();
    }

    private void render()
    {
        //Set the rotation values
        cube.RotateX = tX.Value;
        cube.RotateY = tY.Value;
        cube.RotateZ = tZ.Value;

        //Cube is positioned based on center
        Point origin = new Point(picCube.Width / 2, picCube.Height / 2);

        picCube.Image = cube.drawCube(origin);
    }

    private void tX_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        render();
    }

    private void tY_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        render();
    }

    private void tZ_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        render();
    }
}

internal class Math3D
{
    public class Point3D
    {
        //The Point3D class is rather simple, just keeps track of X Y and Z values,
        //and being a class it can be adjusted to be comparable
        public double X;
        public double Y;
        public double Z;

        public Point3D(int x, int y, int z)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Z = z;
        }

        public Point3D(float x, float y, float z)
        {
            X = (double)x;
            Y = (double)y;
            Z = (double)z;
        }

        public Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Z = z;
        }

        public Point3D()
        {
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "(" + X.ToString() + ", " + Y.ToString() + ", " + Z.ToString() + ")";
        }
    }

    public class Camera
    {
        //For 3D drawing we need a point of perspective, thus the Camera
        public Point3D Position = new Point3D();
    }

    public static Point3D RotateX(Point3D point3D, double degrees)
    {
        //Here we use Euler's matrix formula for rotating a 3D point x degrees around the x-axis

        //[ a  b  c ] [ x ]   [ x*a + y*b + z*c ]
        //[ d  e  f ] [ y ] = [ x*d + y*e + z*f ]
        //[ g  h  i ] [ z ]   [ x*g + y*h + z*i ]

        //[ 1    0        0   ]
        //[ 0   cos(x)  sin(x)]
        //[ 0   -sin(x) cos(x)]

        double cDegrees = (Math.PI * degrees) / 180.0f; //Convert degrees to radian for .Net Cos/Sin functions
        double cosDegrees = Math.Cos(cDegrees);
        double sinDegrees = Math.Sin(cDegrees);

        double y = (point3D.Y * cosDegrees) + (point3D.Z * sinDegrees);
        double z = (point3D.Y * -sinDegrees) + (point3D.Z * cosDegrees);

        return new Point3D(point3D.X, y, z);
    }

    public static Point3D RotateY(Point3D point3D, double degrees)
    {
        //Y-axis

        //[ cos(x)   0    sin(x)]
        //[   0      1      0   ]
        //[-sin(x)   0    cos(x)]

        double cDegrees = (Math.PI * degrees) / 180.0; //Radians
        double cosDegrees = Math.Cos(cDegrees);
        double sinDegrees = Math.Sin(cDegrees);

        double x = (point3D.X * cosDegrees) + (point3D.Z * sinDegrees);
        double z = (point3D.X * -sinDegrees) + (point3D.Z * cosDegrees);

        return new Point3D(x, point3D.Y, z);
    }

    public static Point3D RotateZ(Point3D point3D, double degrees)
    {
        //Z-axis

        //[ cos(x)  sin(x) 0]
        //[ -sin(x) cos(x) 0]
        //[    0     0     1]

        double cDegrees = (Math.PI * degrees) / 180.0; //Radians
        double cosDegrees = Math.Cos(cDegrees);
        double sinDegrees = Math.Sin(cDegrees);

        double x = (point3D.X * cosDegrees) + (point3D.Y * sinDegrees);
        double y = (point3D.X * -sinDegrees) + (point3D.Y * cosDegrees);

        return new Point3D(x, y, point3D.Z);
    }

    public static Point3D Translate(Point3D points3D, Point3D oldOrigin, Point3D newOrigin)
    {
        //Moves a 3D point based on a moved reference point
        Point3D difference = new Point3D(newOrigin.X - oldOrigin.X, newOrigin.Y - oldOrigin.Y, newOrigin.Z - oldOrigin.Z);
        points3D.X += difference.X;
        points3D.Y += difference.Y;
        points3D.Z += difference.Z;
        return points3D;
    }

    //These are to make the above functions workable with arrays of 3D points
    public static Point3D[] RotateX(Point3D[] points3D, double degrees)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points3D.Length; i++)
        {
            points3D[i] = RotateX(points3D[i], degrees);
        }
        return points3D;
    }

    public static Point3D[] RotateY(Point3D[] points3D, double degrees)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points3D.Length; i++)
        {
            points3D[i] = RotateY(points3D[i], degrees);
        }
        return points3D;
    }

    public static Point3D[] RotateZ(Point3D[] points3D, double degrees)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points3D.Length; i++)
        {
            points3D[i] = RotateZ(points3D[i], degrees);
        }
        return points3D;
    }

    public static Point3D[] Translate(Point3D[] points3D, Point3D oldOrigin, Point3D newOrigin)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points3D.Length; i++)
        {
            points3D[i] = Translate(points3D[i], oldOrigin, newOrigin);
        }
        return points3D;
    }

}

internal class Cube
{
    //Example cube class to demonstrate the use of 3D points and 3D rotation

    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public int depth = 0;

    double xRotation = 0.0;
    double yRotation = 0.0;
    double zRotation = 0.0;

    Math3D.Camera camera1 = new Math3D.Camera();
    Math3D.Point3D cubeOrigin;

    public double RotateX
    {
        get { return xRotation; }
        set { xRotation = value; }
    }

    public double RotateY
    {
        get { return yRotation; }
        set { yRotation = value; }
    }

    public double RotateZ
    {
        get { return zRotation; }
        set { zRotation = value; }
    }

    public Cube(int side)
    {
        width = side;
        height = side;
        depth = side;
        cubeOrigin = new Math3D.Point3D(width / 2, height / 2, depth / 2);
    }

    public Cube(int side, Math3D.Point3D origin)
    {
        width = side;
        height = side;
        depth = side;
        cubeOrigin = origin;
    }

    public Cube(int Width, int Height, int Depth)
    {
        width = Width;
        height = Height;
        depth = Depth;
        cubeOrigin = new Math3D.Point3D(width / 2, height / 2, depth / 2);
    }

    public Cube(int Width, int Height, int Depth, Math3D.Point3D origin)
    {
        width = Width;
        height = Height;
        depth = Depth;
        cubeOrigin = origin;
    }

    //Finds the othermost points. Used so when the cube is drawn on a bitmap,
    //the bitmap will be the correct size
    public static Rectangle getBounds(PointF[] points)
    {
        double left = points[0].X;
        double right = points[0].X;
        double top = points[0].Y;
        double bottom = points[0].Y;
        for (int i = 1; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            if (points[i].X < left)
                left = points[i].X;
            if (points[i].X > right)
                right = points[i].X;
            if (points[i].Y < top)
                top = points[i].Y;
            if (points[i].Y > bottom)
                bottom = points[i].Y;
        }

        return new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)Math.Round(right - left), (int)Math.Round(bottom - top));
    }

    public Bitmap drawCube(Point drawOrigin)
    {
        //FRONT FACE
        //Top Left - 7
        //Top Right - 4
        //Bottom Left - 6
        //Bottom Right - 5

        //Vars
        PointF[] point3D = new PointF[24]; //Will be actual 2D drawing points
        Point tmpOrigin = new Point(0, 0);

        Math3D.Point3D point0 = new Math3D.Point3D(0, 0, 0); //Used for reference

        //Zoom factor is set with the monitor width to keep the cube from being distorted
        double zoom = (double)Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 1.5;

        //Set up the cube
        Math3D.Point3D[] cubePoints = fillCubeVertices(width, height, depth);

        //Calculate the camera Z position to stay constant despite rotation            
        Math3D.Point3D anchorPoint = (Math3D.Point3D)cubePoints[4]; //anchor point
        double cameraZ = -(((anchorPoint.X - cubeOrigin.X) * zoom) / cubeOrigin.X) + anchorPoint.Z;
        camera1.Position = new Math3D.Point3D(cubeOrigin.X, cubeOrigin.Y, cameraZ);            

        //Apply Rotations, moving the cube to a corner then back to middle
        cubePoints = Math3D.Translate(cubePoints, cubeOrigin, point0);
        cubePoints = Math3D.RotateX(cubePoints, xRotation); //The order of these
        cubePoints = Math3D.RotateY(cubePoints, yRotation); //rotations is the source
        cubePoints = Math3D.RotateZ(cubePoints, zRotation); //of Gimbal Lock
        cubePoints = Math3D.Translate(cubePoints, point0, cubeOrigin);

        //Convert 3D Points to 2D
        Math3D.Point3D vec;
        for (int i = 0; i < point3D.Length; i++)
        {
            vec = cubePoints[i];
            if (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z >= 0)
            {
                point3D[i].X = (int)((double)-(vec.X - camera1.Position.X) / (-0.1f) * zoom) + drawOrigin.X;
                point3D[i].Y = (int)((double)(vec.Y - camera1.Position.Y) / (-0.1f) * zoom) + drawOrigin.Y;
            }
            else
            {
                tmpOrigin.X = (int)((double)(cubeOrigin.X - camera1.Position.X) / (double)(cubeOrigin.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * zoom) + drawOrigin.X;
                tmpOrigin.Y = (int)((double)-(cubeOrigin.Y - camera1.Position.Y) / (double)(cubeOrigin.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * zoom) + drawOrigin.Y;

                point3D[i].X = (float)((vec.X - camera1.Position.X) / (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * zoom + drawOrigin.X);
                point3D[i].Y = (float)(-(vec.Y - camera1.Position.Y) / (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * zoom + drawOrigin.Y);

                point3D[i].X = (int)point3D[i].X;
                point3D[i].Y = (int)point3D[i].Y;
            }
        }

        //Now to plot out the points
        Rectangle bounds = getBounds(point3D);
        bounds.Width += drawOrigin.X;
        bounds.Height += drawOrigin.Y;

        Bitmap tmpBmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tmpBmp);

        //Back Face
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[0], point3D[1]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[1], point3D[2]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[2], point3D[3]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[3], point3D[0]);

        //Front Face
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[4], point3D[5]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[5], point3D[6]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[6], point3D[7]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[7], point3D[4]);

        //Right Face
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[8], point3D[9]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[9], point3D[10]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[10], point3D[11]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[11], point3D[8]);

        //Left Face
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[12], point3D[13]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[13], point3D[14]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[14], point3D[15]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[15], point3D[12]);

        //Bottom Face
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[16], point3D[17]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[17], point3D[18]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[18], point3D[19]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[19], point3D[16]);

        //Top Face
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[20], point3D[21]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[21], point3D[22]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[22], point3D[23]);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, point3D[23], point3D[20]);

        g.Dispose(); //Clean-up

        return tmpBmp;
    }

    public static Math3D.Point3D[] fillCubeVertices(int width, int height, int depth)
    {
        Math3D.Point3D[] verts = new Math3D.Point3D[24];

        //front face
        verts[0] = new Math3D.Point3D(0, 0, 0);
        verts[1] = new Math3D.Point3D(0, height, 0);
        verts[2] = new Math3D.Point3D(width, height, 0);
        verts[3] = new Math3D.Point3D(width, 0, 0);

        //back face
        verts[4] = new Math3D.Point3D(0, 0, depth);
        verts[5] = new Math3D.Point3D(0, height, depth);
        verts[6] = new Math3D.Point3D(width, height, depth);
        verts[7] = new Math3D.Point3D(width, 0, depth);

        //left face
        verts[8] = new Math3D.Point3D(0, 0, 0);
        verts[9] = new Math3D.Point3D(0, 0, depth);
        verts[10] = new Math3D.Point3D(0, height, depth);
        verts[11] = new Math3D.Point3D(0, height, 0);

        //right face
        verts[12] = new Math3D.Point3D(width, 0, 0);
        verts[13] = new Math3D.Point3D(width, 0, depth);
        verts[14] = new Math3D.Point3D(width, height, depth);
        verts[15] = new Math3D.Point3D(width, height, 0);

        //top face
        verts[16] = new Math3D.Point3D(0, height, 0);
        verts[17] = new Math3D.Point3D(0, height, depth);
        verts[18] = new Math3D.Point3D(width, height, depth);
        verts[19] = new Math3D.Point3D(width, height, 0);

        //bottom face
        verts[20] = new Math3D.Point3D(0, 0, 0);
        verts[21] = new Math3D.Point3D(0, 0, depth);
        verts[22] = new Math3D.Point3D(width, 0, depth);
        verts[23] = new Math3D.Point3D(width, 0, 0);

        return verts;
    }
}
```

}

Right now when I run this code in visual studio 2015 it creates a 3D cube but how do i modify it to where I can get a pyramid?